# Significato di "pigliare" in questo brano

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Geremia mette via il coltello, gira daccapo la manovella e Enrico Caruso ricomincia a soffrire. Chissà se quando troverà la figlia sarà meno infelice. Rocco il coltello lo lascia bene in vista sul tavolo, tanto per chiarire chi ha avuto ragione nella disputa. Vita passa il dito sulla lama. È cosí affilata che **piglia** a sanguinarle il dito. Rocco dice che le sta bene, perché le bambine non devono giocare coi coltelli.

Nei dizionari che ho consultato ho visto che "pigliare" può significare "prendere, afferrare, far presa". Tuttavia, non mi sembra che questi significati abbiano senso nel brano precedente. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "pigliare" nel testo sopra citato?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curioso. Il verbo “prendere”, fra i tanti usi che ha, si può usare anche, in costruzioni del tipo “prendere a fare qualcosa”, per dire “cominciare a fare qualcosa”. Nella [voce del Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/prendere) è l'accezione 16.a:

> **a.** letter. Seguito da *a* con l’infinito di un verbo, incominciare: *prese a dire*; *presero a fuggire*; *Poi le schiere a ferir prese, vibrando Le mortifere punte* (V. Monti); *i fatti che prendiamo a raccontare* (Manzoni).

Ammetto che non avevo presente l'uso di “pigliare” in questo senso (e nelle espressioni idiomatiche non sempre è possibile sostituire una parola con un sinonimo), ma dando un'occhiata in giro ne ho trovato almeno un'attestazione: a [p. 411 di *A New Plain and Useful Introduction to the Italian*,](https://books.google.it/books?id=kRFDUf5XmR0C&pg=PA411&dq=%22pigliare%20a%20%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ15imtr7gAhUvsKQKHbbCB28Q6AEILTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) curata da John Kelly nel 1739, si legge “Pigliare a fare una cosa - To undertake, or set about a thing”, il che conferma che l'uso non è nuovo.

[image: Pigliare a fare una cosa - To undertake, or set about a thing.]

Nel nostro contesto, quindi, chi narra sta semplicemente dicendo che il dito comincia a sanguinare.

Answer (score 1):

Raramente, è legata anche alla definizione di [*piglio*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piglio1/) nell'accezione di intraprendere un'azione all'improvviso. Nel dialetto toscano più forbito ed arcaico tutt'oggi è saltuariamente possibile sentirlo.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!